# What Snake is this? (Found at my door in Raebareli, North India)

Tags: species-identification, species, herpetology, snake

Found [this snake](https://youtu.be/29PQvcp-mIE) at my door in Raebareli, North India. We of course allowed it to go away peacefully.

Could someone please identify it for me?

[image: Snake]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the venomous [Common Krait (Bungarus caeruleus)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_krait), one of the [Big Four Indian Snakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Four_(Indian_snakes)),  responsible for the highest number of snake bites in India.

Comment: How close was it to humans when it was noticed? Are these aggressive snakes?